# How to redirect to the next page without pressing a button with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I want to move to the next page without clicking on button with flutter.
Juste after changing the value of a button, I have to redirect to the next page after some delay without any self interaction.
this is the code :

```
   initialData: BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected,
                      builder: (c, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.data == BluetoothDeviceState.connected) {
                          return ElevatedButton(
                            child: const Text('CONNECTED'),
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => MainScreen())),
                          );
                        }
```

Comment: can you add more code and explain more? what do you mean by `Just after changing the value of a button` ?

Comment: @eamirho3ein I edited my question. I want to redirect to the next screen just after the button text is Connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if (snapshot.data == BluetoothDeviceState.connected) {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()));
  });
  return Text('CONNECTED');
}
```

Comment: @rania you need call `WidgetsBinding` before return. check my update.

Comment: why I cannot redirect to the previous page ?

Answer (score 0):

While the connection is depend on bool, you can do

```dart
if (snapshot.data == BluetoothDeviceState.connected) {
     // a frame delay
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()));
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried this : `     return (
                            Text('CONNECTED')     
                           WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                           Navigator.of(context).push(MainScreen());
                });
                                      );`   but I got : Expected to find ')'

Comment: add a `)` on last